# iPad Safari doesn't animate while touching

Tags: css, ipad, ios, animation, safari

I'm experimenting with css animations on an iPad. I'm finding that while an animation is happening (.e.g a rotating div), if the user is touching the screen currently running animations get choppy and new animations don't start till the user stops touching. I'm assuming that iOS isn't updating the dom while the user touches or a scroll is happening.

Is there some trick to force Safari to continue drawing while the touch or user action is happening?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, there is no trick.